Tf-idf Matrix problem with the fit_transform
I am doing a typical sexism identification in Twitter with spacy and scikitlearn. I load the data without problems. The problem is when I try to transform the data. I have this loop to introduce in lstDocsEXIST the new data.
for row in dataset.itertuples(index=False):
       
        doc = nlp(row.text)
        
        sentence_tokens = [sent.text.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
        words_lemmas = getToken(doc)
        pos_tags = [token.pos_ for token in doc] 
        
        words_without_stopwords = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
        lstDocsEXIST.append((sentence_tokens, words_lemmas, pos_tags, words_without_stopwords))
        lstObjetiveClass.append(row.task1)
        index += 1

The getToken method is:
def getToken(docSpacy):
    listTokens = []
    for token in docSpacy:
        listTokens.append(token.lemma_)
    return listTokens

After this modifications, I create the tf-idf Matrix in this way:
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=dummy, preprocessor=dummy, ngram_range=(1, 3)) 
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(lstDocsEXIST)
    lstFeaturesTFIDFByComment = tfidf_matrix.toarray()

The problem is that in the method fit_transform doesn't allow that type of data.
It returns this error:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
Is there any way to process or transform all the information without making each of them a unique string?
